Find list of Vnets/Subnets that access a key vault in azure
I am trying to analyse the network traffic to an azure key vault, and would like to obtain a list of Vnets/Subnets that have accessed this key vault.
Is there a way to do this?
If not, is there a way to grab the IPs that have accessed this resource? Then I can work backwards from there.
The following doesn't like "CallerIpAddress"
AzureDiagnostics
| where ResourceProvider == "MICROSOFT.KEYVAULT"
| where OperationName == "GetSecret" or OperationName == "SetSecret" or OperationName == "DeleteSecret"
| summarize by CallerIpAddress

'summarize' operator: Failed to resolve scalar expression named 'CallerIpAddress'

Also, this doesn't have to be done KQL, if there is a way to do it through the CLI, either PowerShell or Az, I'm more than happy to do that too.
Thanks

As your passing wrong OperationName to check the Operation names using KQL query, the correct names are : SecretGet,SecretSet and SecretDelete, refer the MS DOC for details.

'summarize' operator: Failed to resolve scalar expression named 'CallerIpAddress'


OperationName == "GetSecret" or OperationName == "SetSecret" or OperationName == "DeleteSecret"

As your passing invalid OperationNames to check the operations in KQL query , to fetch the callerIP details, the correct operation names are : SecretGet,SecretSet and SecretDelete, refer the MS DOC for details.

Note: You cannot fetch the list of VNet/Subnet names that accessed a KeyVault, but you can only fetch the IP addresses and endpoints.

    AzureDiagnostics
    | where ResourceProvider =="MICROSOFT.KEYVAULT" 
    | where OperationName == "VaultGet" or OperationName == "SecretGet" or OperationName == "SecretSet" or OperationName == "SecretDelete"
    | project TimeGenerated,Resource, ResourceProvider,OperationName, requestUri_s, CallerIPAddress

Output:

Reference: Azure Key Vault logging  &  Monitoring Azure Key Vault
